# what is .random. in this statement?

Tags: python, numpy

```
numpy.random.randn(100)
```

I understand numpy is the name of the imported module and randn is a method defined within the module but not sure what .random. is

Thanks and happy new year!

Comment: It's a module inside `numpy` that contains methods for sampling, see the docs - https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html

Comment: You don't need to know what it is to use it.  Check the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Yann's answer is definetly correct but might not make the whole picture clear. 
The best analogy for package structure are probably folders. Imagine the whole **numpy** package as big folder. In said folder are a bunch of files, these are our functions. But you also have **subfolder**. *random* is one of these subfolders. It contains more files (functions) who are grouped together because they have to do with the same thing, namely randomness.

```
numpy
├── arccos
├── vectorize
├── random
│   ├── randn
│   ├── <more functions in the random subfolder>
│   <more functions in the numpy folder>
```

Answer (score 1):

The .random part is a module within numpy,how you can confirm this is to use the python interpreter

```
#first import numpy into the interpreter
import numpy 

#this is so the interpreter displays the info about the random module
numpy.random
```

Output should be something like "<module 'numpy.random' from 'path to module'>